# No sound in Debian 9 for most of the start ups of the system (sound card is recognized)

Tags: debian, audio, alsa

I installed **Debian 9** 64-bit a couple days ago in a **Compaq Presario** desktop. Everything was going ok until I found that there was no sound. Initially this was solved with a reboot. Unfortunately in most of the successive start ups of the system the sound didn't work (about 25 of let's say 30 times).

I made sure that the system recognized the sound card and that a kernel driver was loaded (I think that this kernel driver is the right one cause the sound worked for a few sessions, as stated above. The kernel driver is **ice1724**). I also used **alsamixer** to make sure that every channel was not muted and installed the **pavucontrol** package to check that the correct sound card was selected. More information of the state of ALSA in the system can be found [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=35b38e11fe7542af517c5c1b81cc697f561aebec), which is a report generated using the **alsa-info.sh** script downloaded from the alsa-project website.

The original desktop sound card stopped working, so another one was installed (this occurred a few years ago and the sound had worked well until I installed Debian), namely an **Encore enm232-8via** sound card. Nonetheless, the system still recognizes 2 sound cards (this was checked using lscpi), because the old one is integrated to the motherboard.

While looking for a possible solution for the no sound problem I read that having multiple sound cards could cause issues, that's why I added a file in **/etc/modprobe.d** that ended in **.conf** which forced the system not to load the kernel module of the old sound card. Here is the content of such file:

```
# options snd_ice1724 model=av710
blacklist snd_hda_intel
```

As you can see, I also tried to add the model option to the kernel module associated with the newer sound card, cause when I checked the kernel logs (using **dmesg**) a message appeared saying that there is no matching model for ice1724. As I thought that solving this could lead to the solution I tried some models listed on the Module snd-ice1724 section of [this page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/sound/alsa-configuration.html#module-snd-ice1724), but they made no difference (also I couldn't figure out exactly which one is the proper one for the Encore card if there is any).